# Execution order of Activity Functions in Azure Durable Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I use Azure Durable Functions as a simple way to queue and execute long running SQL computations in a reliable way (as it provides a queueing and retry mechanism, with state persistence).

Each time a user triggers a new computation (let's say to generate a report for a product), a new orchestration instance is started, which itself runs two activity functions (one to compute the report data, and one to generate and send the file).
While the computation is still in progress, the user is free to request another one (for another product).
The goal is to deliver the first report as soon as possible, and then proceed with the second one, etc.

The SQL database is a performance bottleneck but that's not an issue as long as there is never more than one computation running at a time. The following settings are set in host.json to prevent parallel executions:

```
"maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 1,
"maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 1,
```

The code looks like this:

```
[Function("ReportFunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData request, [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client)
{
    string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString();
    string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync("ProcessingOrchestrator", timestamp);
    return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(request, instanceId);
}

[Function("ProcessingOrchestrator")]
public static async Task RunOrchestratorAsync([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    string? timestamp = context.GetInput<string>();
    await context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessingActivity", timestamp + "#1");
    await context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessingActivity", timestamp + "#2");
}

[Function("ProcessingActivity")]
public async Task RunActivityAsync([ActivityTrigger] string tag)
{
    _logger.LogWarning(tag);
    await Task.Delay(3000); // compute data or generate file
}
```

The problem with this solution is that, when two reports are requested at the same time, activities are executed in the following order:

```
activity #1 of first orchestrator
activity #1 of second orchestrator
activity #2 of first orchestrator
activity #2 of second orchestrator
```

Is there a way to force activities to execute in the order they were requested by the user?
Basically, I need FIFO instead of LIFO.

I had a look at eternal orchestrations, singleton orchestrations, entity functions and critical sections but I can't see how that would help. Especially since I still need to be able to cancel an orchestration without impacting the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by leveraging the [lock mechanism provided by Durable Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=function-based%2Cin-process%2Cpython-v2&pivots=csharp#entity-coordination).

The idea is to define a global pseudo-entity, with a unique ID:

```
private readonly EntityInstanceId entityId = new("GlobalEntity", string.Empty);
```

And just change the orchestrator function to:

```
    [Function("ProcessingOrchestrator")]
    public async Task RunOrchestratorAsync([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        string? timestamp = context.GetInput<string>();
        await using (await context.Entities.LockEntitiesAsync(entityId))
        {
            await context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessingActivity", timestamp + "#1");
            await context.CallActivityAsync("ProcessingActivity", timestamp + "#2");
        }
    }
```

My understanding is that an additional "operation queue" is then involved, and this queue is FIFO.
I would still appreciate any opinion on this solution.

Comment: After some tests, I ended up having activities waiting endlessly for a failed orchestrator. I guess we're not supposed to use Durable Functions in this way. I'm afraid I will have to implement my own task management system...